# How to import data from Mingle Forum plugin to bbPress?

Tags: import, bbpress

How to import data from Mingle Forum plugin (free) to bbPress?

I wasn't able to find any custom importer, so I was thinking someone might have run into this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

bbPress includes an importer to import Mingle Forums (WordPress Plugin)

http://codex.bbpress.org/import-forums/